# 504 on Graph copy of large folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

We have a process that includes copying and renaming a template folder.  The template folder is ~20MB. We are getting a 504 with code "UnknownError."  [According to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response), we should be [receiving a monitor response back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/long-running-actions-overview?tabs=http), but that is not happening.

It should also be noted we are using the `Microsoft.Graph v4.35.0` nuget (latest at time of writing).  The SDK returns the error "nameAlreadyExists" when Fiddler tells me it's a 504 with error "UnknownError."  Something in the SDK is not handling the error correctly.

Comment: Are the source and target in the same doclib? same site?

Comment: Yes, the copy operation drops the new folder right next to the source.